# Est-ce qu'écrire septante pour 70 et nonante pour 90 est valide sur un chèque en France ?

Tags: nombres, france, belgique

Est-ce qu'écrire *septante*, *octante* | *huitante* et *nonante* sur le chèque d’une banque française (ou potentiellement de tout pays francophone n’utilisant pas les nombres réformés) est susceptible d’entraîner le non-encaissement de ce chèque auprès de la dite banque ?

Étant donné que la réponse peut varier d’un pays à l’autre (France, Québec, pays du Maghreb et le reste de l’Afrique francophone) vous êtes bien évidement invités à détailler, si vous le pouvez, la situation pour chaque pays ou collectivité :)

Comment: J'ai pas eu de problèmes avec les banques durant ma période d'adaptation mais j'ai bien eu des commerçants inquiets qui m'ont demandé de refaire le chèque.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the French language but about the legal implications of some existing usages.

Comment: En Belgique, le plus incongru est de rédiger un chèque :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1. La dénomination de chèque, insérée dans le texte même du titre et exprimée dans la langue employée pour la rédaction de ce titre ;

Source : [www.legifrance.gouv.fr](http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006184470&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006072026&dateTexte=20040709)

La question est donc : est-ce que septante est un mot français ?

> Il est à noter pourtant que les mots *septante*, *octante*, *nonante* figurent 
>       dans toutes les éditions du *Dictionnaire de l’Académie française*. Encore 
>       conseillés par les *Instructions officielles* de 1945 pour faciliter l’apprentissage 
>       du calcul, ils restent connus dans l’usage parlé de nombreuses régions de l’Est 
>       et du Midi de la France, ainsi qu’en Acadie.

Source : [www.academie-francaise.fr](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#78_strong-em-septante-octante-nonante-em-strong)

Donc OUI, on peut écrire septante sur un chèque.

Answer (score 6):

Voici la réponse spécifique pour le Québec.
Au niveau de la légalité, l'[Association canadienne des paiements](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CJMBEBYwCA&url=http://www.cdnpay.ca/imis15/pdf/pdfs_publications/consumer_guide_cheques_fr.pdf&ei=Qd82U_SYEKitsQT844GgDA&usg=AFQjCNGOZKKiWZS2DH0opJuWZKso-VvkBw&sig2=A0Dx5cMfi7JJi2613Yt7LQ&bvm=bv.63808443,d.cWc) indique que:

> Lorsque vous faites un chèque, vous devez indiquer la date, le nom du bénéficiaire, le montant en mots ainsi que le montant en chiffres, et votre signature. La loi n’exige pas d’écrire le montant en mots, mais l’ACP recommande vivement de le faire, puisque le montant en mots sert à confirmer le montant en chiffres en cas de question sur ce dernier.

Donc comme @mansuetus l'a indiqué, la question est: Est-ce que *septante* est un mot?
Voici ce qu'en disent les autorités officielles au [Québec](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870053):

> Les termes *soixante-dix* et *septante* ont deux natures grammaticales; ils peuvent être des adjectifs numéraux cardinaux invariables ou des noms masculins invariables.
>
> Le terme *septante* est un synonyme de *soixante-dix* tout à fait courant en Belgique, en Suisse, dans la République démocratique du Congo et au Rwanda; il est également attesté dans certaines régions de l'est de la France et dans le sud-ouest de la Nouvelle-Écosse. *Septante* a déjà été d'un usage plus répandu en France, mais il a commencé à y être supplanté par *soixante-dix* dès le 15<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Fait intéressant, les gens écrivent et utilisent très souvent l'adjectif *soixante et dix* qui est maintenant déconseillé par l'OQLF. En conclusion, il semble tout à fait légal d'écrire ces mots sur un chèque au Québec, mais je n'oserais personnellement pas m'y aventurer puisqu'avant aujourd'hui, je n'avais jamais entendu ces mots de ma vie. Je soupçonne donc que leurs utilisations pourrait vous apporter des problèmes malgré tout.

Comment: Je confirme que ça fonctionne. J'ai écrit il y a quelques semaines un chèque sur lequel j'ai écrit substitué *huitante-quelque-chose* au *quatre-vingt-quelque-chose* plus habituel au Québec, et il a passé *comme du beurre dans la poêle*.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai envoyé un chèque de septante et quelques euros à l'administration fiscale qui me l'a retourné, prétextant qu'il devait être écrit en français. Je l'ai renvoyé au chef de service avec photocopie de la page du dictionnaire et il a été encaissé. Donc, oui, on peut écrire septante sur un chèque français, mais il vaut mieux avoir un dictionnaire pour prouver son bon droit face à un créancier peu éduqué.

Answer (score 2):

Il me semble qu'il ne devrait pas avoir de raison légale de refuser un tel chèque en France.

La loi précise qu'un chèque doit être rédigé dans la même langue que le titre lui-même (ou l'une des langues pour les chèques bilingues) et septante, huitante et nonante sont des mots présents dans les dictionnaires français.

Answer (score 1):

Pour ce que ça vaut : [http://www.generation-nt.com/...](http://www.generation-nt.com/reponses/valeur-legale-mots-septante-nonante-france-entraide-2786971.html)

C'est un forum, pas une source officielle. Cependant je crois que l'argument employé est valable, à savoir que l'écriture en lettres est là pour remplacer l'écriture numérique si celle-ci est illisible.

La réponse serait donc oui.

Par ailleurs il semblerait que septant et nonante soient des mots du dictionnaire français.